# No module in jupyter VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to

`import miepython` but get `No module named 'miepython'`

It works great to import the module when working with a web based jupyter notebook that I have opened from the terminal in the correct (conda) environment.

It works great if executed in a .py file in VS Code with the correct (conda) environment.

It used to work great in a jupyter notebook in VS Code until a few days ago. Now:
`No module named 'miepython'`

I can see no difference in the PATH environment when comparing the PATH for VS Code and the web based jupyter. I have tried to reset the vscode settings.

Maybe the latest update of VS Code triggered this behavior... There are no other obvious reasons I can think of.

So, I am clueless. **Why doesn't VS Code jupyter find the module miepython?**

Any help is much appreciated!